# What "conjunctions" to be used here

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I and my mother are planning to go on a trip next week, but my father doesn't want us to go. On top of this he just got the news that the **weather** is going to be severe next week.

As I am not a native speaker, I am having difficulties to say this in the format given below.

> _________ My father didn't want us to go on trip, on top of this, he just got the news about the bad weather; ___________ now there is no chance that he would let us go.

Help me with some **conjunctions** that can be used in the blanks.

Comment: Why do you think the sentence needs conjunctions in the blanks?

Comment: Respected @BellaSwan in my native language we put conjunctions in this context, that's why I want to know if there are any to make the sentence stressful.

Comment: I don't think any conjunctions would be needed here.

Comment: @BellaSwan could I have any other ways to express it.

Comment: The way you are saying it seems alright already.

Comment: @BellaSwan Thank you!